# Extract string values from query parameters Url in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-dynamic-links, query-string

Im recieving a single key in the form of deeplink url: https://example.in/?meetingCode=usertest?meetingToken%3DtZSI6InN5c3Rl7RfdQ4JEbnMkBfNmanH6VrRC4FzcFgOJEU2BmJEBAzo

i want to retrive meetingCode & MeetingToken string values from it. At current it is extracting the value of either meetingCode or meetingToken. How to extract both the strings?

```
deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode")deeplink?.queryParameter("meetingToken)
```

This is the code:

```
 private fun handleDynamicLink() {
    Firebase.dynamicLinks
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            val deepLink: Uri?
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link

                deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode")?.let { joinMeeting(it) }

            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { _ ->
            toast(getString(R.string.main_error_fetch_dynamic_link))
        }
}
```

Please help me how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: Why not just wrap them together into `Pair`?
`deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode") to deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingToken")`

Comment: How to wrap them into pair?

Comment: `val pair = deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode") to deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingToken")`

Comment: Tried it but still getting the same error. No value passed for "meetingToken".

Comment: Actually i want to recieve the values so meeting will start:

(`private fun joinMeeting (meetingCode:String, meetingToken:String) {
        MeetingUtils.startMeeting(
            this, meetingCode,
            meetingToken)

    }`)

Comment: This is a runtime error? Have you tried to debug it? Does `println(deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode"))
println(deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingToken"))` return meaningful values or `null`?

Comment: Yes i tried it. Its showing this:

(`https://example.in/?meetingCode=usertest?meetingToken%3DeyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7InVzZXIiOnsi?)

Comment: Its showing the single key deeplink url the one i posted in question

Comment: ? (`deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode", "meetingToken").`?)              
 is there a way we can pair them in 1